# How can I move data between different controllers in rails while also receiving user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture

I'm relatively new to rails, and trying to write a program that involves querying data (a `user_id` and list of `options`) from an external API in one controller (`Controller A)`, pushing the `options` to a view such that a user can select the option they want (via `<select_tag>`, and then sending both the `user_id` and `selected_option` to a different controller (`Controller B`).

I use an event listener to send an ajax post request to `Controller B` when an item is selected from my dropdown list.  The issue is that the ajax request creates a new class instance, where in reality I want to reference the instance of Controller B that I instantiated in `Controller A`.

How I can get both the `user_id` and `selected_option` into `Controller B` based on the architecture I have described?

Comment: You send the data you need with the request--you don't access controller instances from other different controller instances: controllers are stand-alone, per-request.

Comment: Calling one controller method from another is a bit of an antipattern, in my opinion. Instead, define a third, static class that has the shared methods. Call that from the controller

Comment: Could you add some pseudo code to the question @Matt? It would likely make this a lot easier to help with.